# Split string and number each split with unique ID

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

How can I split a string on a comma and return a numbered instance of each split? For example the following code

```
$SourceDir = "D:\SQLServer2016\BackupOne,D:\SQLServer2016\BackupTwo"
$SourceDir -split ','
```

Returns

```
D:\SQLServer2016\BackupOne
D:\SQLServer2016\BackupTwo
```

I would like to it also return the numbered instance of each string for example

```
D:\SQLServer2016\BackupOne,1
D:\SQLServer2016\BackupTwo,2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm curious whay you need this. It feels like an XY problem. The returned value is an array that already has a unique identifier for each value (the index).

Comment: In SQL I have a backupconfig table with two columns SourceDir and RoboCopyDir. Both columns contain data which is rightly or wrongly unnormalised and comma separated, as shown in the example. In order to eventually ROBOCOPY data from location1 of SourceDir to location one of RoboCopy dir, I need to know the positional location of each string in the cell i.e 1 to 1, 2 to 2 and 3 to 3 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are fixing the wrong problem, but here is a way to do it.:

```
$SourceDir = "D:\SQLServer2016\BackupOne,D:\SQLServer2016\BackupTwo"
$i = 1
$SourceDir -split ',' | %{'{0},{1}' -f $_, $i; $i++}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to create a PSObject

```
$SourceDir = "D:\SQLServer2016\BackupOne,D:\SQLServer2016\BackupTwo"
$SplitDir = $SourceDir -split ','

$index = 0
$Backups = @()

foreach($dir in $SplitDir)
{
    $index ++
    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Directory = $dir
            BackupNumber = $index
            }

    $Backups += $Object
}

$Backups
```